# How can I create binary label from two tables

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, join

I'm trying to analyse a trend in data that I have with Pandas. I have a two tables and I'd like to create a new binary column in one if the UID and PID in that row exists in the other table. An example of the tables I currently have would be:

```
>>> df_a = pd.DataFrame({"UID": [123, 456, 789, 012], "PID": [12, 55, 56, 89], "TIM": [76, 54, 21, 25]})
>>> df_a 
   PID  TIM  UID
0   12   76  123
1   55   54  456
2   56   21  789
3   89   25  010

>>> df_b = pd.DataFrame({'UID': [221, 012, 653, 456], 'PID': [17, 89, 51, 55], 'FOO': [2347, 32447, 3234, 7999]})
>>> df_b
     FOO  PID  UID
0   2347   17  221
1  32447   89  010
2   3234   51  653
3   7999   55  456
```

And I'd like the end result to be:

```
>>> df_a
   PID  TIM  UID  PUR
0   12   76  123    0
1   55   54  456    1
2   56   21  789    0
3   89   25  010    1
```

But I'm not sure exactly how to go about doing this. I thought a `left join` would be the way to go but I'm having trouble pulling that off also. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: yes you want to do a left join (called a merge in pandas)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use left join with [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) or [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html), then test `FOO` column if not `NaN` to `boolean mask` which is converted to `0,1` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df_a['PUR'] = df_a.join(df_b.set_index(['PID','UID']), on=['PID','UID'])['FOO']
                  .notnull().astype(int)
print (df_a)
   PID  TIM  UID  PUR
0   12   76  123    0
1   55   54  456    1
2   56   21  789    0
3   89   25   12    1
```

---

```
df_a['PUR'] = pd.merge(df_a, df_b, how='left', on=['PID','UID'])['FOO'].notnull().astype(int)
print (df_a)
   PID  TIM  UID  PUR
0   12   76  123    0
1   55   54  456    1
2   56   21  789    0
3   89   25   12    1
```

Another solution is test by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df_a['PUR']  = df_a.set_index('PID')['UID'].isin(df_b.set_index('PID')['UID'])
                   .astype(int).values
print (df_a)
   PID  TIM  UID  PUR
0   12   76  123    0
1   55   54  456    1
2   56   21  789    0
3   89   25   12    1
```

EDIT:

It seems you need [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) by both columns:

```
#added duplicates
df_b = pd.DataFrame({'UID': [221, 12, 456, 456], 
                     'PID': [17, 89, 55, 55], 
                     'FOO': [2347, 32447, 3234, 7999]})
print (df_b)
     FOO  PID  UID
0   2347   17  221
1  32447   89   12
2   3234   55  456 <-duplicates by both columns
3   7999   55  456 <-duplicates by both columns

df_b = df_b.drop_duplicates(['PID','UID'])
df_a['PUR'] = df_a.join(df_b.set_index(['PID','UID']), on=['PID','UID'])['FOO']
                  .notnull().astype(int)
print (df_a)
   PID  TIM  UID  PUR
0   12   76  123    0
1   55   54  456    1
2   56   21  789    0
3   89   25   12    1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I try this I get a `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`. It turned out I had duplicates in the columns I was interested in so checked and made sure any duplicates were dropped but I still get this error when I try the `join`

Comment: I got a work around by appending `.values` to the end of the `join`, but now I have a weird problem where the join is somehow creating exactly 43 more elements than there exists in the original dataframe, returning a `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index` exception

Comment: please check edited answer - I think problem is in duplicates in `df_b` by both columns.

Answer (score 2):

`merge` with `indicator=True` almost gets you there

```
df_a.merge(df_b[['PID', 'UID']], how='left', indicator=True)

   PID  TIM  UID     _merge
0   12   76  123  left_only
1   55   54  456       both
2   56   21  789  left_only
3   89   25  012       both
```

With a tweak using `map`

```
m = dict(left_only=0, both=1)
df_a.assign(
    PUR=df_a.merge(df_b[['PID', 'UID']], how='left', indicator=True)._merge.map(m))

   PID  TIM  UID  PUR
0   12   76  123    0
1   55   54  456    1
2   56   21  789    0
3   89   25  012    1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a left join but it gets a bit weird if you want to have that result.

```
df_b['PUR'] = 1
df_a = pd.merge(df_a, df_b, how='left', on=['PID', 'UID'])
df_a['PUR'] = df_a['PUR'].apply(lambda x: 1 if pd.notnull(x) else 0)
df_a = df_a.drop('FOO', axis=1)
```

I would suggest using a pure `apply` instead:

```
df_a['PUR'] = df_a.apply(lambda x: int(x['UID'] in df_b['UID'].values or
                                       x['PID'] in df_b['PID'].values), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy's in1d(). You can use it to implement in further cases too, where left join might fail

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    df_a = pd.DataFrame({"UID": [123, 456, 789, 012], "PID": [12, 55, 56, 89], "TIM": [76, 54, 21, 25]})

    df_b = pd.DataFrame({'UID': [221, 012, 653, 456], 'PID': [17, 89, 51, 55], 'FOO': [2347, 32447, 3234, 7999]})

    UID_a = df_a['UID'].values
    UID_b = df_b['UID'].values
    PID_a = df_a['PID'].values
    PID_b = df_b['PID'].values

    x = np.in1d(UID_a, UID_b)
    y = np.in1d(PID_a, PID_b)

    PUR = x + y

    df_a['PUR'] = PUR
    df_b['PUR'] = PUR
```